# hg status is slow the first time

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Does anybody know why `hg status` is slow (3-10 secs) the first time it's called from the command line on a windows client (I'm assuming it is cached after that).

`hg status` is a local operation and it should not take that long especially with empty repos.

This is the case on both an active repository with several changes and a brand new repo with no files. So the size of the repo does not seem to be a factor on the performance.
Thanks!

Comment: is that on windows? can you see if you have the same experience with the command line?

Comment: Yes. Running windows & I am using the command line.

Comment: maybe using hg --profile would give some helpful hints.

Comment: Can you be clearer about "first time"? First time after installing hg? First time after reboot? First time in each new cmd window? First time in any single repo?

Comment: @shambulator Sorry for not being clear. I meant after not using HG for some time :)  ex. After not interacting with it for a day or two, or after a reboot..etc

I haven't exactly pinned it down the event that causes it to be slow, so my best guess is "time" meaning if enough time has passed I'm guessing the caching expires & it takes longer to run "hg status". I noticed the same among my development team as well, so it's not just my machine...

@tonfa What is hg -profile? that does not seem to be a valid command param in Mercurial 1.5.3

Comment: two "-", not one. Like `hg --profile status`

Comment: Ahh! Excellent! I was doing 'hg --profile' only

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you run the `hg status` command, Mercurial has to scan almost every directory and file in your repository so that it can display file status. Hg has to perform at least one expensive system call for each managed file to determine whether it's changed since the last time Mercurial checked, there's no avoiding that.

I believe the reason subsequent calls to `hg st` are faster is because of the cached information the OS retains about all recently accessed files —avoiding disk access if the file has not been modified—. Sometimes the files themselves may even remain memory mapped by the OS or cached altogether on the HDD buffer.

Edit: also, if you haven't invoked hg in a while, the OS will need to read the hg executable and its dependencies from disk, since they might not be cached on RAM already.

Comment: Thanks! That answers it! however this means that an empty (or a very small) repo should be VERY fast which is not true in all the cases I've seen.

Comment: Yeah, because even if the repo is small (or empty!), the OS still needs to load & cache Hg plus all its dependencies (e.g. Python runtime)